# Android Navigation Architecture Component go back to a specific fragment with arguments

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have a stack like this
A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> B1 -> B2 -> C

I am using same fragment with new instance.
when I am normally navigating back with popBackStack, it is working fine.
And I want to go from fragment C to Fragment A2, though I went but the problem is when I click back from fragment A2 it stays same and then I click back again then I go to fragment A1.

Please help me out. I really don't wanna use savedStateHandle.
Is there any conventional way? just like navigating forward with data, we could go backwards with data something like singleTop and onNewIntent.

I tried pretty much every solution provided but no one posted scenario like this also I don't wanna use savedStateHandle.
Please help me out guys.

Here's my nav-graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_private_trade"
    app:startDestination="@id/privateTradeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/privateTradeFragment"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.PrivateTradeFragment"
        android:label="f_private_trade"
        tools:layout="@layout/f_private_trade">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_privateTradeFragment_to_createOrderFragment"
            app:destination="@id/createOrderFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_privateTradeFragment_to_enterTradeCodeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/enterTradeCodeFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/createOrderFragment"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.CreateOrderFragment"
        android:label="f_create_order"
        tools:layout="@layout/f_create_order">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_createOrderFragment_to_selectSearchItemFragment1"
            app:destination="@id/selectSearchItemFragment1" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/enterTradeCodeFragment"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.EnterTradeCodeFragment"
        android:label="f_enter_trade_code"
        tools:layout="@layout/f_enter_trade_code" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/selectSearchItemFragment1"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.SelectSearchItemFragment"
        android:label="f_select_search_item"
        tools:layout="@layout/f_select_search_item">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_selectSearchItemFragment1_to_selectSearchItemFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/selectSearchItemFragment2" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/selectSearchItemFragment2"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.SelectSearchItemFragment"
        android:label="f_select_search_item"
        tools:layout="@layout/f_select_search_item">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_selectSearchItemFragment2_to_selectSearchItemFragment3"
            app:destination="@id/selectSearchItemFragment3" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/selectSearchItemFragment3"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.SelectSearchItemFragment"
        android:label="f_select_search_item"
        tools:layout="@layout/f_select_search_item">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_selectSearchItemFragment3_to_addPaymentMethodFragment"
            app:destination="@id/addPaymentMethodFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addPaymentMethodFragment"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.AddPaymentMethodFragment"
        android:label="AddPaymentMethodFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addPaymentMethodFragment_to_choosePriceAmountFragment1"
            app:destination="@id/choosePriceAmountFragment1" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/choosePriceAmountFragment1"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.ChoosePriceAmountFragment"
        android:label="ChoosePriceAmountFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_choosePriceAmountFragment1_choosePriceAmountFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/choosePriceAmountFragment2" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/choosePriceAmountFragment2"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.ChoosePriceAmountFragment"
        android:label="ChoosePriceAmountFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_choosePriceAmountFragment2_to_additionalConfigurationFragment"
            app:destination="@id/additionalConfigurationFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/additionalConfigurationFragment"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.AdditionalConfigurationFragment"
        android:label="f_additional_configuration"
        tools:layout="@layout/f_additional_configuration">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_additionalConfigurationFragment_to_orderSummaryFragment"
            app:destination="@id/orderSummaryFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/orderSummaryFragment"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.OrderSummaryFragment"
        android:label="f_order_summary"
        tools:layout="@layout/f_order_summary">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderSummaryFragment_to_orderCreatedFragment"
            app:destination="@id/orderCreatedFragment" />
        <action android:id="@+id/action_orderSummaryFragment_to_selectSearchItemFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderSummaryFragment_to_selectSearchItemFragment1"
            app:destination="@id/selectSearchItemFragment1"
            app:popUpTo="@id/selectSearchItemFragment1"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderSummaryFragment_to_selectSearchItemFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/selectSearchItemFragment2"
            app:popUpTo="@id/selectSearchItemFragment2"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderSummaryFragment_to_selectSearchItemFragment3"
            app:destination="@id/selectSearchItemFragment3"
            app:popUpTo="@id/selectSearchItemFragment3"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderSummaryFragment_to_choosePriceAmountFragment1"
            app:destination="@id/choosePriceAmountFragment1"
            app:popUpTo="@id/choosePriceAmountFragment1"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderSummaryFragment_to_choosePriceAmountFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/choosePriceAmountFragment2"
            app:popUpTo="@id/choosePriceAmountFragment2"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/orderCreatedFragment"
        android:name="com.obsidiam.android1.ui.privatetrade.OrderCreatedFragment"
        android:label="f_order_created"
        tools:layout="@layout/f_order_created">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderCreatedFragment_to_privateTradeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/privateTradeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/privateTradeFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

and I am navigating back like this.

```
val idAndFrom = when (pos) {
            1 -> {
                Pair(
                    R.id.action_orderSummaryFragment_to_selectSearchItemFragment,
                    AppConstants.FROM_SELECT_CURRENCY
                )
            }
            2 -> {
                Pair(
                    R.id.action_orderSummaryFragment_to_selectSearchItemFragment,
                    AppConstants.FROM_SELECT_PAYMENT_METHOD
                )
            }
            3 -> {
                Pair(
                    R.id.action_orderSummaryFragment_to_choosePriceAmountFragment,
                    AppConstants.FROM_ADD_PAYMENT_METHOD
                )
            }
            4 -> {
                Pair(
                    R.id.action_orderSummaryFragment_to_choosePriceAmountFragment,
                    AppConstants.FROM_PRICE
                )
            }
            else -> {
                Pair(
                    R.id.action_orderSummaryFragment_to_selectSearchItemFragment,
                    AppConstants.FROM_SELECT_COIN
                )
            }
        }

        findNavController().navigate(
            idAndFrom.first,
            bundleOf(AppConstants.FROM_WHERE to idAndFrom.second),
            navOptions {
                popUpTo(
                    if (pos < 3) R.id.selectSearchItemFragment else R.id.choosePriceAmountFragment
                ) {
                    inclusive = true
                }
            }
        )
```

Here Fragment A is SelectSearchItemFragment and Fragment B is ChoosePriceAmountFragment and Fragment C is OrderSummaryFragment.

Comment: Please provide your navigation graph and code.

Comment: @SamChen I have edited the description. Also I tried to make multiple destinations of same fragment and that way I was able to achieve my use case. But, I wonder if that is the correct way or not?

Comment: Thanks @SamChen I was able to achieve this similarily, That's why never look back to this question. Thanks for your help.